# Why subscription screen doesn't open if the Subscription is not active? Xcode Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have used showManageSubscriptions function show subscription sheet with subscription options within the application but when subscription haven’t purchase or not active then sheet can not open.

```
@available(iOS 15.0.0, *)
    func showManageSubscription(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene) async {
        do {
            try await StoreKit.AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: windowScene)
        } catch {
            print("Sheet can not be opened")
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to open sheet in this case even subscription haven’t purchase or not active? So user can at least buy again.

I want Apple default subscription sheet like this to buy subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions), you can only use it for **upgrade, downgrade, or cancel**. I recommend you to design a custom IAP screen, you can use tools like [revenuecat](https://www.revenuecat.com) to manage